# Cannot remove the layered navigation Block by using layout xml?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

To call the layered navigation I use this call and it worked

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();?>
```

For remove it I use this in `default.xml`

```
<reference block name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

But when I remove this above calling code fails because of what I do.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that is impossible to remove your block (which is called directly on your phtml) by using layout xml. We can try two options:

1. We can set this block in your xml also. And, then remove it via layout.
2. Try to add conditions for this block: when it shows or not.

Comment: I am not getting u proper

Comment: No read my question

Comment: You tried to remove this line code: `<?php echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();?>`, but you failed?

Comment: No  second code to remove i used

Comment: `<?php echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();?‌​>` when calling this way, we cannot remove it via layout xml `<reference block name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />`. My answer was for this case.

Comment: But i removed usinf this

Comment: You **cannot**.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a typo there:

```
getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnavv')->toHtml();?>
```

Instead of leftnavv that should be leftnav.

Comment: No it mt editing mistake u suppose catalog.leftnav on both code

Comment: In which `phtml` file are you calling this?

Comment: i want call layered navigation in list.phtml  file

Comment: Well I think you should create your own theme with your own layout and put the block whererwere you want. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html#layout_overview_blocks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo.  It should be:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();?>
```

to this:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav') ?>
```

and on your custom theme file called `default.xml` you will need to complement with this block.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Change the **referenceContainer** named **sidebar.main**